# UITable View Cell Button issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have Custom Table View Cell In That I Have Two UIButton and One Text Field Named As edit and cancel and one textField. When I Click on edit at same time TextFeild Interaction is Enabled And Cancel Button Image Should Change. Its Working Fine For Me!!

But When I am Clicking On Edit Button Another Cells Cancel bitton Image id Changed Automatically! I know that this happening because I'm reusing the cell!! But I'm not able to find a solution...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    simpleTableIdentifier = @"MenuNameCell";
    cell = (MenuNameCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuNameCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"---------new cell agin");          
    }
    else
    {
        for (UIView *view in [cell.contentView subviews])
                [view removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"---------older use");
       // _checkButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
       // _cancelButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    }

    // Creating Label Menu Name
    _nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 11, 82, 21)];
    _nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _nameLabel.text =  [_hotel._orderedMenus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Creating Label Menu Cost
    _amountMenu   = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(167, 13, 44, 21)];
    _amountMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _amountMenu.text  = [[_hotel._menuPrices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

    // Creating Text Field For Order Quantity
    _textFieldQuantity = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,14,42,21)];
    _textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _textFieldQuantity.text = [[_hotel._selectedQuantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

    // Creating Button For Check Order
    _checkButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(232, 13, 25, 28)];
    [_checkButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_checkButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    // Creating Button For CANCEL Order
    _cancelButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(265, 13, 25, 28)];
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_cancelButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(cancelOreder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_cancelButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    // Adding All To Call Content View
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_amountMenu];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_textFieldQuantity];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_checkButton];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_cancelButton];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: please post your editQuantity: method

Comment: Your question would be a lot easier to read if you didn't start every word with a capital letter.

Comment: -(IBAction)editQuantity:(UIButton *)sender  { 
    _textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    button = (UIButton *)sender;
    row = button.tag;
    NSLog(@"Check Button index is %d",row);
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_over.png"];
    [_checkButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImageCancel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _cancelButton.tag =  0;
}

Comment: @occulus bettert way you could answer this post

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I don't think that this is because of reuse cell anyways if you think then do a favor for me just keep all of your code in if; but while you must check is anything on your click event which alter you id(s).

One more thing generally its become our habit to use tag for this purpose, but we've something in our hand which is provided by apple to work-out for such thing that is Association. Here, you should try:-

> ***objc_setAssociatedObject***

by which you always have reference of your cell or anything for which you make association.
Just google and, for a glance I'm just pasting a code below check it:(But you need to work according to your requirement)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView != popTbl)
    {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
        cell = (CustomizeConditionVC *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomizeConditionVC" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        } 
        cell.lbl.text = [objArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        cell.lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:(17.0)]; 
        cell.lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
        cell.lbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.12 green:0.27 blue:0.34 alpha:1.0]; 
        cell.lbl.autoresizingMask = NO;
        NSString* lblStringLen = NULL;
        lblStringLen = [objArr objectAtIndex:0];
        unsigned int kFactor = -1;
        kFactor = cell.lbl.frame.size.width/[lblStringLen length];
        CGRect rect = cell.lbl.frame;
        rect.size.width = kFactor * [[objArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] length];
        [cell.lbl setFrame:rect];
        [cell.txtField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        cell.txtField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:(17.0)];    
        cell.txtField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.50 green:0.50 blue:0.50 alpha:1.0]; 

        CGRect rectTxtField = [cell.txtField frame];
        rectTxtField.size.height = 27;
        [cell.txtField setFrame:rectTxtField];
        [cell.txtField setDelegate:self];
        [cell.txtField setTag:indexPath.row];

        [cell.txtView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell.txtView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0]];
        cell.txtView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:(17.0)]; 
        cell.txtView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.50 green:0.50 blue:0.50 alpha:1.0]; 
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        [cell.btn1 setTag:1];
        [cell.btn2 setTag:2];
        [cell.btn3 setTag:3];
        [cell.btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonAtCellControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonAtCellControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonAtCellControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.btnClearence addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonAtCellControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btnMaintenance addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonAtCellControl:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btnClearence setHidden:YES];
        [cell.btnMaintenance setHidden:YES];

//        //////////////
        objCell = cell;
//        //////////////
        int getVersionFromCategory = [[self ExtractTheFirstCharBeforePeriodOfDevice] intValue];

       // cell.btn1 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn1.frame];

        switch (indexPath.row) 
        {
            case 2:
            case 4:
                cell.txtView = [UITextView SetTheBorderProperties:cell.txtView];
                [cell.txtView setHidden:NO];
                [cell.txtView setDelegate:self];
                [cell.txtField setHidden:YES];
                [cell.smallBtn setHidden:YES];
                [cell.largeBtn setHidden:YES];
                [cell.txtView setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.lbl.frame.origin.x+13, cell.lbl.frame.origin.y + cell.lbl.frame.size.height + 3, 295-39, (121-(cell.lbl.frame.origin.y + cell.lbl.frame.size.height +3)+89))];
                [cell.btn1 setHidden:YES];
                [cell.btn2 setHidden:YES];
                [cell.btn3 setHidden:YES];
                if(indexPath.row == 4)
                {
                    [cell.txtView setHidden:YES];
                    [cell.btnClearence setHidden:NO];
                    [cell.btnMaintenance setHidden:NO];
                } 
                 break;
            case 3:
                [cell.btn1 setHidden:NO];
                prototype1 = btn1 = cell.btn1;
                /////////New Entry on Date:Nov.07...
                prototype2 = cell.btn2;
                prototype3 = cell.btn3;
                ////////
                [cell.btn2 setHidden:NO];
                [cell.btn3 setHidden:NO];
                [cell.btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.txtField.frame.origin.x, cell.txtField.frame.origin.y, cell.txtField.frame.size.width/3, cell.txtField.frame.size.height)];
                [cell.btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(5+cell.txtField.frame.origin.x+cell.txtField.frame.size.width/3+5, cell.txtField.frame.origin.y, cell.txtField.frame.size.width/3, cell.txtField.frame.size.height)];
                [cell.btn3 setFrame:CGRectMake(15 + cell.txtField.frame.origin.x+2*(cell.txtField.frame.size.width/3)+5, cell.txtField.frame.origin.y, cell.txtField.frame.size.width/3, cell.txtField.frame.size.height)];
                [cell.txtField setHidden:YES];
                [cell.smallBtn setHidden:YES];
                [cell.largeBtn setHidden:YES];

//                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
//                                      initWithTitle:@"Hover display.." message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cell.btn1.frame.size.width] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
//                [alert show];
//                [alert release];
                break;
            default:
                [cell.btn1 setHidden:YES];
                [cell.btn2 setHidden:YES];
                [cell.btn3 setHidden:YES];
                [cell.txtView setHidden:YES];
                [cell.txtView setDelegate:nil];
                [cell.smallBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(DepictingPopUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [cell.largeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(DepictingPopUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                objc_setAssociatedObject(cell.smallBtn,SMALL_BTN_REF,indexPath,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
                objc_setAssociatedObject(cell.largeBtn,SMALL_BTN_REF_1,indexPath,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
                objc_setAssociatedObject(cell.largeBtn, LARGE_BTN_REF, cell.txtField, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
                objc_setAssociatedObject(cell.smallBtn, CELL_TO_CELL_REF, cell.txtField, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
                break;
        }

//        int getVersionFromCategory = [[self ExtractTheFirstCharBeforePeriodOfDevice] intValue];
//        if(getVersionFromCategory > 3)
//        {
//            cell.btn1 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn1 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
//            cell.btn2 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn2 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
//            cell.btn3 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn3 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
//        }
//        cell.btn1 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn1 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
//        cell.btn2 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn2 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
//        cell.btn3 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn3 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];

        if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"PreviewCase"])
        {
            switch (indexPath.row) 
            {
                case 0:
                    cell.txtField.text = [(NSMutableDictionary*)getTheConditionListVC objectForKey:@"qty"];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    //cell.txtField.text = [(NSMutableDictionary*)getTheConditionListVC objectForKey:@"extraCol"];
                    cell.txtField.text = [(NSMutableDictionary*)getTheConditionListVC objectForKey:@"condition"];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cell.txtField.text = [(NSMutableDictionary*)getTheConditionListVC objectForKey:@"furtherNote"];
                    cell.txtView.text = [(NSMutableDictionary*)getTheConditionListVC objectForKey:@"furtherNote"];
                    break;
                case 3://liability//+(UIButton*)MButton3DLookForSelected:(UIButton*)_rectForButton AndButtonTitle:(NSString*)_btnTitle
                {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:@"Hover display.." message:[(NSMutableDictionary*)getTheConditionListVC objectForKey:@"liability"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    //[alert show];
                    [alert release];
                    if(getVersionFromCategory > 3)
                    {
                        switch ([[(NSMutableDictionary*)getTheConditionListVC objectForKey:@"liability"] intValue]) {
                            case 1:
                            //case 0:
                                cell.btn1 = [UIButton MButton3DLookForSelected:cell.btn1 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                                cell.btn2 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn2 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                                cell.btn3 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn3 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                cell.btn1 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn1 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                                cell.btn2 = [UIButton MButton3DLookForSelected:cell.btn2 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                                cell.btn3 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn3 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                cell.btn1 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn1 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                                cell.btn2 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn2 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                                cell.btn3 = [UIButton MButton3DLookForSelected:cell.btn3 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }

                    }
//                    else
//                    {
//                        switch ([[(NSMutableDictionary*)getTheConditionListVC objectForKey:@"liability"] intValue]) {
//                            case 1:
//                                //case 0:
//                                cell.btn1 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn1.frame];
//                                cell.btn2 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn2.frame];
//                                cell.btn3 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn3.frame];
//                                break;
//                            case 2:
//                                cell.btn1 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn1.frame];
//                                cell.btn2 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn2.frame];
//                                cell.btn3 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn3.frame];
//                                break;
//                            case 3:
//                                cell.btn1 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn1.frame];
//                                cell.btn2 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn2.frame];
//                                cell.btn3 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:cell.btn3.frame];
//                                break;
//                            default:
//                                break;
//                        }
//                    }
                }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if([[(NSMutableDictionary*)getTheConditionListVC objectForKey:@"extraCol"] intValue] == 4)
                    {
                        //////////////
                        objCell = cell;
                        //////////////

                        [[(CustomizeConditionVC*)objCell btnClearence] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brush_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        [[(CustomizeConditionVC*)objCell btnMaintenance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }
                    else 
                    if([[(NSMutableDictionary*)getTheConditionListVC objectForKey:@"extraCol"] intValue] == 5)
                    {
                        //////////////
                        objCell = cell;
                        //////////////

                        [[(CustomizeConditionVC*)objCell btnClearence] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brush.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        [[(CustomizeConditionVC*)objCell btnMaintenance] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    }   
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            //int getVersionFromCategory = [[self ExtractTheFirstCharBeforePeriodOfDevice] intValue];
            if(getVersionFromCategory > 3)
            {
                cell.btn1 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn1 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                cell.btn2 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn2 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
                cell.btn3 = [UIButton MButton3DLook:cell.btn3 AndButtonTitle:@"gdf"];
            }
            else
            {
//                [cell.btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.txtField.frame.origin.x, cell.txtField.frame.origin.y, cell.txtField.frame.size.width/3, cell.txtField.frame.size.height)];
//                [cell.btn2 setFrame:CGRectMake(5+cell.txtField.frame.origin.x+cell.txtField.frame.size.width/3+5, cell.txtField.frame.origin.y, cell.txtField.frame.size.width/3, cell.txtField.frame.size.height)];
//                [cell.btn3 setFrame:CGRectMake(15 + cell.txtField.frame.origin.x+2*(cell.txtField.frame.size.width/3)+5, cell.txtField.frame.origin.y, cell.txtField.frame.size.width/3, cell.txtField.frame.size.height)];
//                [cell.txtField setHidden:YES];
//                [cell.smallBtn setHidden:YES];
//                [cell.largeBtn setHidden:YES];
                //MCustomizeButtonRect


           /*     
                cell.btn1 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:prototype1.frame];
                cell.btn2 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:prototype2.frame];
                cell.btn3 = [[MCustomizeButtonRect alloc] initWithFrame:prototype3.frame];

            */    

//                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
//                                      initWithTitle:@"Hover display.." message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cell.btn1.frame.size.width] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
//                [alert show];
//                [alert release];

            }
        }
//        prototype1 = cell.btn1;
//        prototype2 = cell.btn2;
//        prototype3 = cell.btn3;
        return cell;
    }
    else 
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50, 201, 47) 
                                           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 
        cell.textLabel.text = @"N/A";
        NSString* dropMenusString = NULL;
        dropMenusString = [[tempOfArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        if ([dropMenusString length] > 0) 
            cell.textLabel.text = dropMenusString;
        //cell.textLabel.text = [[tempOfArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        return cell;
    }
}

Now, access your association as :-

    -(void)DepictingPopUp:(id)sender
    {
        [popTbl isHidden]?[popTbl setHidden:NO]:[popTbl setHidden:YES];
        [popTbl setHidden:NO];
        NSIndexPath* iPath =  nil;
        iPath = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, SMALL_BTN_REF);
        NSIndexPath* iPathNew = nil;
        iPathNew = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, SMALL_BTN_REF_1);
        (iPath)?(associateIndex = iPath.row):(associateIndex = iPathNew.row);
        UITextField* tempField = nil;
        tempField = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, LARGE_BTN_REF);
        UITextField* tempMField = nil;
        tempMField = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, CELL_TO_CELL_REF);
        if(tempField)
        {
            tempTxtField = tempField;
            tempMField = nil;
        }
        else
        {
            tempTxtField = tempMField;
            tempField = nil;
        }
        [popTbl setFrame:[(NatolliAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] GetTheCordinateFromTextFieldDynamically:tempTxtField WithButton:sender isAssociativeRefAvailable:YES IfAvailableThenIndex:associateIndex]];
        [popTbl isHidden]?[popTbl setHidden:NO]:[popTbl setHidden:YES];
        [popTbl setHidden:NO];

        switch (iPath.row || iPathNew.row)
        {
            case 0:
                tempOfArr = quantArr;
                [popTbl reloadData];
                break;
            case 1:
                tempOfArr = conditionArr;
                [popTbl reloadData];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Please note you need to work a/c to your requirement as I just paste one of my code due to my busyness.

In case of any concern just get back to me.

Comment: i am getting my cell position in my asoociation but how to set that position to my other button in cell bcoz i want to change that button image

Comment: Frankly, I'm not getting but if you need to set the position of other buttons which are present on different cells, so what can you do is, first of that button which you've reference take the frame means get CGRect and again reload your table and this time in cellAtRowAtIndexPath, just set this frame to your buttons...it's too simple...:)

Comment: Also, tell me if you're looking anything else...:)

Answer (score 0):

use following code to directly creating new cell without reusing the old one.

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

instead of

```
cell = (MenuNameCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```